# Managed types Mixed types unsupported Visual C++

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

So what im doing is creating a form that bitmaps move around and when they collide they "fight".  The bitmaps are saved a VBot and inherited into child bots which to keep track of the bots i built an array of pointers.  The VBot and BotContainer are .h and .cpp files but when i attempt to create a private BotContainer in Form.h to keep track off the Bots it gives me the error message

Error   1   error C4368: cannot define 'VList' as a member of managed 'Prog3::Form1': mixed types are not supported c:\users\duerst\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\prog 3\prog 3\Form1.h 65  1   Prog 3

What can i do to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing something like this:

```
class BotContainer
{
    ...
};

public ref class Form1
{
private:
    BotContainer VList;

    ...
};
```

This is illegal because managed types can't have members of unmanaged types (and vice-versa). You need to use a *pointer* to a BotContainer, which you instantiate in the constructor and delete in the destructor:

```
public ref class Form1
{
private:
    BotContainer* VList;

public:
    Form1()
    {
        VList = new BotContainer();
        ...
    }

    ~Form1()
    {
        delete VList;
    }
};
```